# IO method blocks:

Tags: java, file, io, buffer

From [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html):

```
public int read(byte[] b) throws IOException
```

> Reads up to b.length bytes of data from this input stream into an
>   array of bytes. This method blocks until some input is available.

What do they mean with "This method block until some input is available?
The main thread blocks? till some InputStream have been passed into the stream?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 'Blocks until some input is available'. The language is perfectly clear. Not a real question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It pretty much means that your program will pause until you give it some input.